# What is the conclusion of this article?

Tags: vocabulary

I am not clear on the usage of 偏上 in the following sentence:

> 此前，《时代》周刊和皮尤研究中心也分别做过类似国家形象的调查。结果均显示，中国的受欢迎程度排名中偏上，但都远远落后于日本的排名。

My translation: Prior to this research, ShiDai publication and Pew did a separate investigation of... Similar countries? All of the results show that China's acceptance rating is... Skewed/biased/prejudiced? But all still lag behind Japan?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 此前，《时代》周刊和皮尤研究中心也分别做过类似国家形象的调查。

Previous to this (research), Time Magazine and Pew Research Center had each done similar national image surveys.

> 结果均显示，中国的受欢迎程度排名中偏上，但都远远落后于日本的排名。

The results all showed, China's popularity is middle to upper, but ranks far behind Japan.

Comment: Ahhh they separately did their own research! OK that makes more sense. So that "pian" actually represents kind kind of a range? From middle to high, correct? Thank you!

Comment: Pian can mean "bias" or "leaning towards," so it's middling but leaning towards high.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at slightly refining Alex's translation:

> 此前，《时代》周刊和皮尤研究中心也分别做过类似国家形象的调查。

Previously, Time Magazine and the Pew Research Center independently carried out similar national image research.

> 结果均显示，中国的受欢迎程度排名中偏上，但都远远落后于日本的排名。

The results indicated that China's popularity is upper-middle, but ranks far behind Japan.